# unsure how to use method correctly

Tags: java

I want to take input from a scanner using .nextInt() and send it to the method below but I'm not sure how.

```
// Method to check the user has enter an integer
 static int checkValidInput ( Scanner scan)
{
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) // 
    {
        scan.next(); // if the input is not an integer it is discarded.

        System.out.println("You did not enter a integer"); // the question is asked again until the right value is entered
    }   

    return scan.nextInt(); // the integer entered is returned to the statement that called the method
}
```

Comment: Your method returns the integer value, so assign it to a variable or use it however you would like

Answer (score 0):

```
int age = checkValidInput(scan);
```

Comment: I was confused about the scanner part and was trying checkValidInput(scan.nextInt());